# How to find the volume bounded by $z=x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}$, and $z=0$ and $y=4$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume for a solid which is bounded with these two cylinders $z=x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}$, and the planes $z=0$ and $y=4$.

First, I have plotted $z=x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}$:

$z=x^{2}$:

[image: z=x^{2}]

$y=x^{2}$:

[image: y=x^{2}]

But they don't form a cylinder; they are parabolas in space.

Am I wrong? Or the problem specification is incorrectly written up?

**UPDATE:**

Now I know that $z=x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}$ are called cylinders.

But I don't how to find the region to be integrated.

So far, I have drawn the other equations (*i.e.*, $z=0$ and $y=4$):

$z=0$:

[image: z=0]

$y=0$:

[image: y=4]

Comment: Hint : You probably know the formula for the volume of the solid that emerges when a curve rotates around the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Peter thanks. In this article http://citadel.sjfc.edu/faculty/kgreen/vector/block1/func/node14.html I found that $z=x^{2}$ is called *parabolic cylinder*; to be a cylinder it must have the form $x^{2}+y^{2}=z$.

Comment: In the actual case, $z=x^{2}$ has no dependence on $y$.